# Brython and Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, brython

I've been playing around with Python for some days and I got to the point where I want to put the code of my Python application on the web. Basically the application is all about asking user a question and counting the score based on user's answers [which he types into the application], which later is returned to the user with appropriate comment.

Now I'd like to publish the application to the web. I found Brython but I have problems with getting it to work, being a newbie in Python and a total newbie in JS.

My code in HTML file looks like that:

```
<html>

        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="brython.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body onload="brython()">

            <script type="text/python" src="filename.py">
            </script>

        </body>

    </html>
```

Basically, filename.py and brython.js are in the same catalogue as this HTML file. Unfortunately, the code triggers nothing. How should I proceed further? What should I read or do?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your `filename.py` should have valid content. The attached example works fine with three files `example.html`, `brython.js` & `test.py`. Python in console vs Brython works slightly different, Start with small examples from that attachment. Happy coding

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxdhq84bcvunhk9/brython-example.zip?dl=0

Comment: The thing is that `filename.py` works in console :( I'm not sure where is the error but thanks for the tip, I'm looking into your files right now :)

Comment: Python in console vs Brython works slightly different, Start with small examples from that attachment. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could start reading the [documentation](http://brython.info/static_doc/en/intro.html?lang=en).

While you are developing you could use the [`debug` option on `brython` function](http://brython.info/static_doc/en/options.html). The errors will appear on the javascript console of you browser.

If you post your *filename.py* maybe we can help you in a more appropriate way. Also, the paths to files should be correct. If you want to share a code snippet where others can see the problem you could use [this jsfiddle](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/wiki/Share-your-Brython-snippet).